# share one vpn connection through windows rras with other clients

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, rras, cisco-vpn, site-to-site-vpn

I'm having a Cisco VPN connection to access our branch office. Since several people using the VPN I'm planing to install the VPN client on one of our server and share it through RRAS to save the licenses (like site - to - site).

I install RRAS on a windows 2008 R2 (svrw2k8r2) and made the static routes on client computers. I could able to ping to the VPN's IP on svrw2k8r2 server but they can't seems to connect to the servers in other branch through this setup.

Below is my setup

My Branch
Server: svrw2k8r2 - Windows 2008 R2
IP: 192.168.40.100/24
VPN IP: 10.0.100.12/8

Clients
Win7
IP: 192.168.40.101 - 110 / 24

Other Branch Servers
IP:10.10.0.10-20/24

Answer (score 0):

You may have to setup NAT to hide your client IP. Others branch may not have the route back to your private lan, as it is not meant for a true site2site at the beginning.

I would add the Nat feature and give it a try.